# document-uri() is not working when using collection()

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, saxon, saxon-c

I'm using saxonche version 12.3.0 installed using pip in Python 3.11.5.

When using `collection()` in XSLT, `document-uri()` doesn't seem to be working.

I've created a small test:

**Python**

```py
import saxonche

with saxonche.PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    xsltproc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()
    executable = xsltproc.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file="test.xsl")
    content = executable.call_template_returning_string()

    print(f"\ncontent:\n{content}")
```

**XSLT 3.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('input?select=*.(xml|XML)&amp;content-type=application/xml')">
            <xsl:message>Processing "{document-uri()}"...</xsl:message>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Processing ""...
Processing ""...
Processing ""...

content:
<doc>First test XML instance.</doc>
<doc>Second test XML instance.</doc>
<doc>Third test XML instance.</doc>
```

**Expected Output**

```
Processing "file:/C:/test_saxonche_collection/input/test_01.xml"...
Processing "file:/C:/test_saxonche_collection/input/test_02.xml"...
Processing "file:/C:/test_saxonche_collection/input/test_03.xml"...

content:
<doc>First test XML instance.</doc>
<doc>Second test XML instance.</doc>
<doc>Third test XML instance.</doc>
```

Is this a bug in Saxon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug in Saxon.

The issue is that by default the collection is not stable<sup>1</sup> and documents read using `collection()` are only added to the document pool if the collection is stable.

From [the docs](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!functions/fn/document-uri):

> Documents read using the collection() function are added to the document pool (and therefore have a document-uri() property) if and only if the collection is stable.

I was able to resolve this two different ways.

The first was by adding the `stable=yes` query param to my `collection()` call:

```
collection('input?select=*.(xml|XML)&amp;content-type=application/xml&amp;stable=yes')
```

The second was by using `base-uri()` instead of `document-uri()`:

```xml
<xsl:message>Processing "{base-uri()}"...</xsl:message>
```

I'm going to stick with using `base-uri()` since there are performance concerns making a collection stable. (Per the docs linked above.)

**Additional Info**

- https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6227
- https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5640
- https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4837

<sup>1</sup>: For more information on what a "stable" collection is, take a look at the [the Saxon documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections). I've summarized a couple of key points here:

From [Collection catalogs](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections/collection-catalogs):

> If stable="false" is specified, however, the URI is dereferenced directly, and the document is not added to the document pool, *which means that a subsequent retrieval of the same document will not return the same node* [emphasis added].

From [Directories as collections](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections/collection-directories):

> Making a collection stable has the effect that the entire result of the collection() function is retained in a cache for the duration of the query or transformation, and any further calls on collection() with the same absolute URI return this saved collection retrieved from this cache.

Comment: For most use cases, in particular with SaxonC where so far I think you can't play much with URI or collection resolvers, simply using `base-uri()` might give the needed URI even without the need to add the `stable`. But that is also in the docs you have linked to.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Yes you're right `base-uri()` does work without changing anything in the `collection()` call. This is probably a better solution since making a collection stable has performance concerns. Updated my answer.

Comment: *if and only if the collection is **stable***:  Here's a reference to what Saxonica means by a [collection being stable](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/sourcedocs/collections.html).   I'd add this link to the phrase avoid confusion that could arise by the implication that the reference is to some broader CS concept regarding collections in general.

Comment: Excellent point @kjhughes. Thanks for supplying the link. Answer updated!

Comment: An alternative approach is to use the uri-collection() function which returns a set of URIs, which you can then retrieve (selectively if you wish) using the doc() function. Documents retrieved using doc() always have a document-uri() property. But this is effectively the same as making the collection stable: all the documents will be locked in memory.